# Add new value to json string in SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I would like to insert new values into a random Json string without using the `Json_modify` function. I am using SQL Server 2016.

For example, let's say I have a Json string like this:

```
{ "a": { "b": "val"} }
```

Now I would like to add a new object into the `Json` string. After adding a object c with value NEW the `Json` string should look like this:

```
{ "a": { "b": "val", "c": "NEW"} }
```

Is there any way to do something like this without using `json_modify`?

I do not want to save the `Json` string into a table. All I want afterwards is a SQL Server procedure which adds a `Json` object into a `Json` string on a defined position.

Thanks

---

How I'd do this with JSON_MODIFY:

```
declare @jsonString nvarchar(4000) = '{"a": {"b":"val"} }'
, @jsonResult nvarchar(4000)
, @path nvarchar(128) = '$.a.c'
, @value nvarchar(128) = 'NEW'

set @jsonResult = JSON_MODIFY(@jsonString, @path, @value)
select @jsonResult
```

Comment: When you say you don't want to use `json_modify`, do you mean you want to use string manipulation instead / what's your reason for not using `json_modify`?

Comment: Actually i would like to create a procedure like json_modify buy using common SQL constructs. This is a exercise for me...

Comment: I don't know if it is necessary to use sql string manipulation.... i can imagine, that it is also possible to select from json objects by using the OPENJSON Function and then union with the new json object. Afterwars it should be possible to use FOR JSON AUTO or FOR JSON PATH to get back a single manipulated json string...

Comment: open json will return a generic table of (key - type - value) unless you specify the keys. string manipulation is probably going to result in quite a cumbersome, slow performing code. I would suggest using actual, real-world solved problems as exercise base. Helping other people with their problems on Stackoverflow has been a great learning tool for me personally. I've learned a lot by answering questions - I would even say more then I've learned by asking questions here.

Comment: Do you think it is possible to see the implementation of json_modify anywhere?

Comment: I do like to know how json_modify works...

Comment: NB: `json_modify` isn't written in SQL itself; so trying to recreate that functionality in SQL would be very hard.  Are you open to using CLR functions?

Comment: ps. I've amended your question to include an example of how it can be done with `json_modify`; to give an example of what you're attempting to achieve.  Please can you check that that does what you'd want (aside from it using `json_modify`)?  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/14857

Comment: Sadly SQL isn't one of the products which MS have open sourced.  Stuff which they have can be found here: https://opensource.microsoft.com

Comment: What I want to do is something like this:



declare \@json varchar(MAX) = '{"a": {"b":"val"} }';

print \@json;

set \@json = JSON_MODIFY(@json, '$.a.c', 'NEW');

print \@json;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your answers and comments. I've already solved the problem, but couldn't solve the stackoverflow question because I'm using foreign libraries. Either way, it was just an exercise for me. In the end, I spent four months dealing with this problem and found a non-trivial solution. As I said before, I can't post it here because I'm embedding foreign code and the author of the foreign code didn't allow me to post it publicly.

Basically it was about editing arbitrary JSON objects in any depth in TSQL. In other words, adding new elements, deleting elements and changing elements and returning the changed JSON object as string. I also didn't want to use the function "JSON_MODIFY" provided by Microsoft.

I intentionally did not want to use JSON_MODIFY because this method is only available in newer SQL Server versions and not in older versions. There are certainly enough developers who would like to edit JSON objects in TSQL but have older SQL Server versions and don't want to buy a new SQL Server license just for this one function. For these people my solution would have been very helpful. But unfortunately not publishable, because foreign code was integrated.

Many thanks to everyone who helped here.

Answer (score 2):

```
    DECLARE @json VARCHAR(MAX)='{ "a": { "b": "val"} }'

    --Collect values in tmp table
    SELECT * INTO #tbljson  FROM OPENJSON(@json,'$.a') WITH ( b VARCHAR(50))

    -- Add new column into tmp table
    ALTER TABLE #tbljson
    ADD c VARCHAR(10) NULL

    --Update value to new column
    UPDATE #tbljson SET c= 'New' WHERE b='val'

    -- get new Json 
    DECLARE @newJson VARCHAR(max)
    SET @newJson=(SELECT * FROM #tbljson FOR JSON PATH, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES)


    -- Update it to original Json.
    SET @json= JSON_MODIFY(@json, '$.a',JSON_QUERY(@newJson))

    SELECT @json
    DROP TABLE #tbljson
```

This could be my solution to the issue. Instead of string operation, I would do this in case Json collection is little bigger, then I would do this. This is cleaner approach then string operation.